# newtonsoft json package requires reinstall every time i open code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, json.net, script-task

I'm writing C# code in a script task in SSIS.  I need to use the Newtonsoft JSON package in the code so i have installed it from NuGet. When it is first installed it works fine, but when I close my code and re-open it to make a change, I have to re-install the package using `update-package -Reinstall` as per the [Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution in Visual Studio Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709733) post.

Why do I have to do this every time?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is this for all packages, or specific to this one? Also browse behavior under "packages" folder, where downloaded nuget packages sits on project close re-open.

Comment: In this case, it was only 1 package i was attempting to install.  It would work until i closed the package.  I ended up installing the assembly to the GAC manually.  Full steps i took to follow.

Comment: installing the assembly to the GAC manually is a bad practice. What if you deploy your project into remote server, other clients etc? I would suggest you to diagnose issue with local install.

Comment: Understood.  I did this locally on my machine for testing and then registered the DLL on the production server for when we are ready to deploy.  We don't have the resources available to spend the time to troubleshoot why this package wouldn't install correctly via the VS interface.

Answer (score 3):

I found that adding the assembly to the GAC manually fixed the issue for me.  To do this:

1. Open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS (SSDT)" in admin mode.
2. Run this command: gacutil -i "assembly name"

For the assembly name, I just needed to browse my local drive for a copy of the DLL i was adding and then use the full file path (C:...Newtonsoft.json.dll) in the "assembly name".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs

Comment: Thank you! Spent all day trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

**Try installing Json.Net from solution explorer:**

- [json.net
  How to Install Json.Net in Visual Studio Projects](https://riptutorial.com/json-net/example/6086/how-to-install-json-net-in-visual-studio-projects)

### Workaround

Instead of using Json.Net you can benefit from `System.Web.Extension` assembly which is a part of the .Net Framework, you can refer to the following link for a step by step guide on how to parse JSON using this assembly:

- [Importing JSON Files Using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5307/importing-json-files-using-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was an option, but adding the assembly to the GAC ended up being much faster and is working perfectly now.