# How to check for a particular key exists in json string or not

Tags: c#, json, ssis, etl

I have the following json string data as input:

```
string json="{"-1":0,"78":6,"79":6,"80":2,"81":16777215,"82":16777215,"83":1,"84":0,"85":0,"86":"2023/05/07","87":0,"88":0,"89":1,"90":1,"124":1,"16":5,"17":null,"18":null,"19":0,"20":2,"21":2000,"22":0,"23":0,"24":0,"25":0,"26":0,"109":0,"110":0,"29":0,"30":0,"31":0,"32":2000,"33":13710,"34":15710,"135":null}"
```

I want to check if any of the key has `-1` so that it can return true or false. How can I achieve this in c#? I could not able to use JSONobject namespace.

Comment: It looks like you have asked lot of questions without accepting any answer. Feel free to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the site rules.

Comment: Why can't you use newtonsoft.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse JSON string within a Script component using JavaSerializer or JSON.Net assemblies and search for the key value.

- [Importing JSON Files Using SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5307/importing-json-files-using-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [newtonsoft json package requires reinstall every time i open code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577736/newtonsoft-json-package-requires-reinstall-every-time-i-open-code/55580854#55580854)

If the JSON data is formal and contains only keys and values then you can search for the following string `"-1":`, if it is found then the `-1` key is found.

```
if(json.contains("\"-1\":")){

//key found

}else{

// key not found

}
```

Comment: That works fine to check if -1 contains in the json string. Another requirement what im expecting is json contains any key other than 1 to 150? How can I do this?

Comment: @nagaraj try using regular expressions

Comment: can you help me in doing that as it involves both regex with string.contains()